# `hdfs dfs -put` command is not executing properly in HDFS

Tags: hdfs

I am trying to execute the following command. However, an error saying `unknown command` is returned.

`hdfs dfs -put /home/cloudera/testfile1 /user/cloudera/input`

I have already created the `/user/cloudera/input` directory correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Hadoop installation directory is not in your PATH.
Try doing this and see if it works:

```
#Update $HOME/.bashrc
# Set Hadoop-related environment variables
export HADOOP_HOME=<Put your HADOOP_HOME_DIR_PATH here>
# Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

[ref](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)